# Why Android R.java file can be in src/ or gen/?

Tags: xml, android

When i started learning android i learned that R.java files goes to /gen folder

recently i saw it on /src file

( in WROX-Professional Android App Dev- sample code downloads ).

How does this work.

and also in some code i saw ( xml layout )

android:id="@+id/R.id.someName" ( i don't remember in which web page i saw this code , sorry ).

I don't understand this, can somebody help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In older versions of Android (prior to 1.5), R.java was located in src/. It's not anymore it you should keep your's in gen/.

About the id, this is a very easy to answer question et let me think you didn't bother to read Android tutorials. You have the answer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html), step 5.

Comment: e-satis      i have seen R.id.SomeNAme being used in XML like this -> android:id ="@+id/SomeName", but see how it is written in the above question.
I couldn't find it in the page you linked me to.
Sorry that i lost track of from which page i saw that piece of code, may be that code itself was wrong.
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It's exactly the same, in the first one you just have the complet path from the R class. Can't see why it bothers you.